# Chaining strong parameters in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

In this Rails controller, I've got a `create` and an `update` method that share some parameters, but I only want the `course_id` to be settable at create. How can I "dry" up these two methods? Is there a way to chain the two `permit`s so I can say "permit description and title" and then add "course_id" to the permit in the create method?

```
def topic_create_params
  params.require(:topic).permit(
    :course_id,
    :description,
    :title
  )
end

def topic_update_params
  params.require(:topic).permit(
    :description,
    :title
  )
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this could work:

```
def topic_params(attrs = [])
  params.require(:topic).permit *([:description, :title] + attrs)
end

def topic_create_params
  topic_params([:course_id])
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ended up with something slightly different from @Hoang Phan's answer using splat operator in method arguments instead...

```
def topic_params(*attrs)
  attrs = ([:description, :title] + attrs).uniq
  params.require(:topic).permit(attrs)
end

def topic_create_params
  topic_params(:course_id, :thing_id)
end
```